# How do I prevent Redactor from wrapping <img> with <p />

Tags: entries, richtext, redactor

I'm looking to have the `<img>` inserted without the wrapping `<p />`. I'm assuming I can tie in to one of the callback functions to do this? There is a `fileUploadCallback` function available but based on nomenclature, doesn't seem like that would help me if I added a path to a remote image versus uploading one.

Has anyone done this yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not sure that this is possible – Redactor has some checks in its code to make sure everything lives within a block-level element like `<p>`.

You might be better off using a Matrix field instead, with Text and Image block types. You can still use a Redactor field within your Text block type; just disable the Image toolbar button on it from your Redactor config in craft/config/redactor/. Give the Image block type an actual Assets field.

Then from your templates you’ll have full control over the image markup.

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}

    {% if block.type == 'text' %}

        {{ block.myRichTextField }}

    {% elseif block.type == 'image' %}

        {% set image = block.myAssetsField.first() %}
        {% if image %}
            <img src="{{ image.url }}" width="{{ image.width }}" height="{{ image.height }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting Redactor's `paragraphize` setting to `false` for your Rich Text field?

http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-paragraphize

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [a plugin called Retcon](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) which uses [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to rewrite HTML content.

Here's how you could unwrap your images using the [retconUnwrap](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft/wiki/Unwrap) filter in a template:

```
{{ entry.body|retconUnwrap('img') }}
```

(Of course, this won't actually remove the `<p>` tags in your content; it'll only strip them out when that content is rendered.)